# Fill historic close prices in portfolio (xts)

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have portfolio data in xts format `b`

```
            PRENOM      RIC     
2015-09-12 "johnn"     "ML.PA" 
2015-09-19 "johnn"     "RNO.PA"
2015-09-19 "vincent"   "AIR.PA" 
2015-09-19 "vincent"   "MC.PA"
```

I want to add a column with the close price for each stock. So far I have use quantmode's getSymbols and and an ugly for loop with a tryCatch for skipping symbols that do not work.

```
require(quantmod)
 for(i in 1:length(b))
{
  tryCatch({
a<-getSymbols(b[i]$RIC,auto.assign=FALSE)
b$Amount[i]<-Cl(a[as.Date(index(b[i]))])}, 
error=function(e){})
}
```

This does what i need but takes very very long on a larger xts with many dates/symbols and I'm looking for a faster solution.

Comment: I just added the `require(quandmod)` which contains `Cl`. I never used `data.table` so I worry about the opportunity cost. Do you have any sample to get me started the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:
Currently you are downloading the data for several years. You can speed up by limiting the data to a single date.

```
a<-getSymbols(b[i]$RIC,auto.assign=FALSE,
              from=as.Date(index(b[i]), to=as.Date(index(b[i])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really obvious. It still downloads on each field perhaps dl all RICs once before iterating is even faster. Can you edit your code and close the brackets?